# Get pixel info from SDL2 texture

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm currently writing a simple program using SDL2 where you can drag some shapes (square, circle, triangle, etc) into a canvas and rotate them and move them around. Each shape is represented visually by a SDL texture that is created from a PNG file (using the IMG_LoadTexture function from the SDL_image library).

The thing is that I would like to know whether a certain pixel from the texture is transparent, so that when someone clicks on the image I could determine if I have to do some action (because the click is on the non transparent area) or not.
Because this is some school assignment I'm facing some restrictions, that is, only use SDL2 libraries and I can't have some map where I can look up if the pixel in question is transparent because the images are dinamically selected. Furthermore I thought about using a SDL surface for this task creating them from the original images but due to the fact that the shapes are being rotated through the texture that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this by using [Render Targets](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetRenderTarget).

```
SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, target);
... render your textures rotated, flipped, translated using SDL_RenderCopyEx
SDL_RenderReadPixels(renderer, rect, format, pixels, pitch);
```

With the last step you read the pixels from the render target using [SDL_RenderReadPixels](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderReadPixels) and then you have to figure out if the alpha channel of the desired pixel is zero (transparent) or not. You can read just the one pixel you want from the render target, or the whole texture, which option you take depends on the number of hit tests you have to perform, how often the texture is rotated/moved around, etc.

Comment: The documentation says "WARNING: This is a very slow operation, and should not be used frequently. ", I'm not sure if this function is suitable for this purpose.

Comment: Did some testing, it sure is "very slow", it takes around 15 ms to transfer even a 32 x 32 square of RGBA pixels (and I have a fairly modern, fast PC). That alone will take up most of your frame on 60 FPS. I'd recommend doing something else if you need to do this every frame.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your texture using the SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING flag and lock your texture before being able to manipulate pixel data. To tell if a certain pixel is transparent in a texture make sure that you call

```
SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(t, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
```

this allows the texture to recognize an alpha channel.

Try something like this:

```
SDL_Texture *t;

int main()
{
    // initialize SDL, window, renderer, texture
    int pitch, w, h;
    void *pixels;

    SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(t, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);

    SDL_QueryTexture(t, NULL, &aw, &h);
    SDL_LockTexture(t, NULL, &pixels, &pitch);
    Uint32 *upixels = (Uint32*) pixels;

    // you will need to know the color of the pixel even if it's transparent
    Uint32 transparent = SDL_MapRGBA(SDL_GetWindowSurface(window)->format, r, g, b, 0x00);

    // manipulate pixels
    for (int i = 0; i < w * h; i++)
    {
        if (upixels[i] == transparent)
            // do stuff
    }

    // replace the old pixels with the new ones
    memcpy(pixels, upixels, (pitch / 4) * h);

    SDL_UnlockTexture(t);

    return 0;
}
```

If you have any questions please feel free to ask. Although I am no expert on this topic.

For further reading and tutorials, check out http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php. Tutorial 40 deals with pixel manipulation specifically.

I apologize if there are any errors in method names (I wrote this off the top of my head).

Hope this helped.

Comment: Looking at the documentation for SDL_LockTexture, it appears that this makes pixel data available only for write access.  Is there another way that pixel data can be accessed for read access?

Comment: @Julian Locking the texture will save the pixels into the void pointer that's passed into it. So if you just want to read then just lock and unlock the texture once and the pixels will be saved.

Comment: @user2437378 Not officially - https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_LockTexture - `As an optimization, the pixels made available for editing don't necessarily contain the old texture data. This is a write-only operation, and if you need to keep a copy of the texture data you should do that at the application level.` It's hard to think of a way this could be implemented, but it  seems dodgy to rely on something they explicitly say not to. Readers relying on this suggestion may be at risk of their code breaking one day, by which point it'd be too late.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, but people posting half-baked answers are really just wasting the posters time and someone else's time that might rely on it, or at least spend 20 minutes attempting to get it to run. In this case, it might be better to put big bold letters, "This Code is NOT complete - Doesn't work,"  so someone isn't likely to waste time attempting to get it to run, at least they would have been warned... Thanks..

Comment: There's another issue with this answer unfortunately, hypothetically even if a streaming texture did allow for read access like this, there's no easy way to transfer pixel data from a render target texture to a streaming texture. From what I've seen, it seems that it's best to leave textures to be write only interfaces to the display's pixels, and never attempt to read that data back. The methods SDL provides for reading data back from the GPU are very slow or nonexistent.